# Wordpress meta_query not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a meta query to get the details less than the compared id. It is working fine if the last id is 999 but it is not working if passing last id as 1000. I tried a lot but still no luck.

Meta Query

```
 $rd_args = array(
'post_type' => 'estate_property',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'no_found_rows' => 'true',
'posts_per_page' => '2',
'order' => 'DESC',  
'meta_query' => array(          
    array(
        'key' => 'ID',
        'value' => $_POST['last_id'],
        'compare' => '<'
    )
  )
);
```

I am not getting where I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: may be conditions are not meeting to fetch results? post your complete code?

Comment: But how it is possible that the condition is matching for 999 but not for 1000. It should show at least the same data which is there for 999.

Comment: I am adding the full code

Comment: its not working for this..http://vcarepro.com/wp-api/wp_get_property_by_type.php?last_id=200

Comment: but working for vcarepro.com/wp-api/wp_get_property_by_type.php?last_id=50   it is behaving strangely. One more info is thar the ID datatype is BigInt in DB.

Comment: You need to check in database, if there are results for 'estate_property' against that ID..it can't give results if there aren't any..

Comment: I am comparing less than in query.... not equal to

Comment: are you kidding me..why is data printing always the same??

Comment: Hey...have you gone through the code...Its a filter dear so data will be same...

Comment: Anyway thanks for the help... I got the solution the issue was with the BigInt data comparison.

Comment: ok i see..but you should have mentioned that in the question..anyways great you worked it out. Good luck..:)

Comment: Without an answer / accepted answer on this, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer, the issue was the datatype of ID in database. I have added the type in meta_query and it started to work. Thanks every one.

```
  'meta_query' => array(          
   array(
    'key' => 'ID',
    'value' => $_POST['last_id'],
    'compare' => '<',
    'type' => 'numeric'
   )
 )
```